# How can i force that tinyMCE does convert <strong> tags into a style property from parent header <p> or some <h>?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor

When the bold button is clicked, the tinyMCE adds a  tag inside de

or  tag, where X is a number from 1 to 6. I would like to change this behaviour to put the bold formating into the style from the parent tag.

Is there any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
tinymce.init({
            inline: true,
            formats: {
                bold: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: { fontWeight: 'bold' } },
                italic: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: { fontStyle: 'italic' } },
                underline: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: { textDecoration: 'underline' } },
            },
```